# Repair tiny hole/scratch in copper pipe

Tags: plumbing, leak, pipe, copper

I discovered a very tiny hole/scratch in a copper pipe in my basement this morning. It looks like the scratch was caused by a screw that was holding up some wood paneling. The hole is in the middle of a run (not at a joint) and drips only once every 5 or 10 seconds. The pipe carries water from the boiler, so ideally the less surgery the better to repair it.

[image]

Apologies for the not great image...hopefully you can see the small scratch on the left side along with the water pooling on the pipe in the middle.

I have a plumber coming out this afternoon but this seems like something I should be able to fix myself with a little solder or something else. Any recommendations?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14360/repair-holes-in-copper-pipe

Comment: Make sure that is the actual area of the leak and the water wasn't running down the pipe from elsewhere. You can use a paper towel to easily detect water running along the pipe.

Comment: Slap a flex tape on that

Comment: Is this pipe running horizontal or vertical? If vertical, it will probably dry and can be soldered. For horizontal runs where there is residual water that could impede the ability to solder, I’ve seen propress fittings used with good results.

Comment: I had a leak that looked like that; it turned out that the whole length had been thinned by internal corrosion. I suggest gently squeezing the pipe with pliers to evaluate.

Comment: Soft patch: http://www.dcfpnavymil.org/Stations/Indexes/sec14/softpatch/PP%20Tip_009_Soft_Patch_(final)16Jul13.pdf  It'll work on smaller pipes too

Answer (score 14):

I have not seen patches hold up on copper. What I find best is to cut it at the hole and sweat a coupler on. It must be dry when you do the soldering or it will leak.

Comment: Yeah, repairing pipe just isn't a reliable approach. Look for a coupler that allows you to slide it fully onto the pipe if you don't have enough movement available. If you do you could use a Sharkbite coupler to avoid soldering.

Comment: If you use a good silver bearing and know how to solder well a coating on the pipe will hold till your great grand children own the house.

Comment: I am quite good at silver soldering I not only do I do water pipe but HVAC. Solder only even if properly done is not as reliable as a coupling especially since the hole was due to wearing a thin spot the coupling provides mechanical strength so although I could seal a leak like that getting the pipe dry would be almost impossible compared to cutting and installing a coupler.

Comment: If you do decide to solder patch, you may as well go as far as cutting a coupling in half and solder on a plate.  If you're accurate enough with a hacksaw the plate can actually go about 60-70% of the way around.  Just cut two slits lengthwise instead of halving it vertically.

Comment: What is a coupler? What kind of coupler? What does it mean to sweat it on? How does one solder onto copper? What equipment does that require? Should one cut out a section (two cuts)? How long should the section be? Must the cut be perfectly perpendicular? Can one do that with a hacksaw? How does one steer the two ends into/onto/over the coupler? Is this something a regular house owner can do? How the hell did this answer consisting of three short sentences get 12 upvotes? While it may be the correct approach, the answer gives almost no guidance at all on how to actually do anything.

Comment: A coupler is a slightly larger piece of copper that tightly slips over the existing pipe. To sweat copper a torch is needed and some non lead solder, and flux. First you cut the damaged pipe a hack saw or pipe cutter for metallic pipe will work then buff the outside of the pipe and inside of the coupling, apply some flux and assemble, the section must be dry , I will usually stuff white bread no crust to make a plug in each end of the pipe just prior to assembling. Then heat it with a torch, apply solder and it will wick into the joint, if done correctly this is the best joint, continued.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the knowledge, tools and skills I would recommend a compression coupler as I had also upvoted that answer. If done correctly the sweated fitting is the best but a compression fitting may work better for you but they are much more expensive and not allowed if the joint is concealed, at least not in my state. Cutting the pipe can be done with many tools but the pipe needs to be debured, depending on how tight the run is a single cut may be all that is needed, but if there is no movement in the pipe ~ 1/8" may need to be removed, lots of votes for a good question

Answer (score 4):

I've had some success with this stuff - it's basically a fiber tape soaked in something like gorilla glue.  But I'd only consider it a temporary repair.  the right way is to cut the pipe and solder in a coupler.

[image]

Comment: I've used '[self-sticking tape](https://store.mocap.com/mocap_en/tpe-x.html?Item=TPE-X10B&QTY=1&Stocked_Color=BLACK&Tape_Width=1.00000&Tape_Length=120.00000&mpn=TPE-X10B&source=googleps&campaignid=657289134&adgroupid=55258360308&feeditemid=&targetid=pla-455258956235&keyword=&matchtype=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlJaejt3U3wIVUQOGCh3OeA__EAQYASABEgKWLvD_BwE)' (sorry I don't know the right term) for minor plumbing repairs.  If you stretch it as you wrap it, you can get a watertight seal.  It won't leave anything on the pipe either as it bonds to itself, not the pipe.

Comment: @JimmyJames That's [self-amalgamating tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-amalgamating_tape), and it's only suitable for temporary use until a proper repair can be made.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sure the answer also refers to a temporary solution.  Having said that, I once cleaned a bunch of gunk out of a waste pipe and discovered that gunk was allowing it to hold water.  I wrapped the pipe with this and it was good for months until I could replace the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You could lay a coating of solder on the pipe, preferably a silver bearing alloy, but you would have to drain that pipe and have "it bone dry".  You could clean the copper, drop the boiler pressure to near zero so the drip stops and lay on a coat of fast dry epoxy. These are 2 ideas, hope this helps  Also, Home DEpot sells a 1/2" copper compression X compression repair coupling in a 12 lingth length.

Comment: I can't remember how many times I had tried, but it took until I had about 10y experience to be able to lay a worthwhile bead over a crack in a copper pipe. But it's not a giant split from freezing that you have to squish back together. Here, I'd give even a novice a 50/50 shot on success the first time, assuming they clean it right, flux it, and don't burn a hole in the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

A common option in the UK (dunno if they are available in other countries) for fixing damaged copper pipes is a [compression repair coupler](https://www.toolstation.com/compression-repair-coupler/p68637?r=googleshopping&rr=marin&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=googleshoppingfeed&mkwid=se02urgN3_dc&pcrid=142003768299&pkw=&pmt=&product=68637&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0caXv9XU3wIVarHtCh0piAzyEAYYASABEgJZVfD_BwE). The coupling has compression fittings on both ends only one of which has a depth stop, so after cutting the pipe you can slide the fitting onto one pipe and then slide it back onto the other with minimal movement of the pipe ends.

Comment: Compression couplers are available but much more expensive, however for a novice this may reduce the chance of a leak +

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the past is to saw a coupler in half lengthwise, use a file to remove the center ridge (unless you can find a "repair coupler" that lacks the ridge), thoroughly clean and flux the pipe and inside of the coupler, tie half of the coupler on with bare copper wire (after cleaning/fluxing it), then (after making sure the pipe is perfectly dry inside) sweat-solder the assembly.  Of course, this requires a couple of inches clearance all around to allow soldering safely.

Anymore, I'd just buy a [SharkBite coupling](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-x-1-2-in-Push-to-Connect-dia-Coupling-Push-Fitting/1000182685?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-RoughPlumbingElectrical-_-PotablePipeFittings-_-1000182685:SharkBite&CAWELAID=&kpid=1000182685&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=2736&k_clickID=go_625853472_34614701230_111134480350_pla-258645561333_c_9019794&gclid=Cj0KCQiApbzhBRDKARIsAIvZue_PAziruaMxV1HFgYaM9pE0n7fun5PlMw0__z0gaX57XxELjGhMQm4aAlg1EALw_wcB), cut the pipe at the defect, then install that coupling.

Answer (score 1):

An option I haven't seen suggested, but one that I've seen several times and employed at least once myself, is to use a clamp to secure a rubber gasket.  There are commercially made clamps 
[image]

or you can cobble your own with a piece of inner tube and a hose clamp.

I wouldn't recommend these for concealed use, but where the patch will be accessible I think they're fine, and probably code-accepted in at least some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the pipe sizes in your country do telescoping, then the next size up in copper pipe will fit exactly over your pipe as a sleeve. I would cut a small section of sleeve, removing the scratched section, and solder the sleeve into place.